# Make folders sync to Amazon S3 faster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have folders in another System. We are mounting it on to a VM and then periodically we do a sync to Amazon S3 using Amazon S3 client. Each folder has lots of sub folders and total size varies from 1GB upto 40-50GB. My transfer to S3 works fine but I have couple of issues.

1. Now transfer of 2GB folder takes 4-5 minutes, which is pretty slow. How can I make the transfer of files/folder faster to Amazon S3 bucket.
2. I see another issue like, if i try to see the size of folder du -sh of a 2GB folder, to see the folder size it takes 8 minutes. Not sure why it takes so much time.

Need advice on making S3 sync with setup I have.

Comment: If you are using the s3 high level api like s3 sync or s3 cp, you probably cannot improve throughput on the script/command level. What's the requirement of where to host this folder? If possible ,hosting this folder/filesystem in ebs volumes(ofc, you need an ec2 VM) would be your best bet since that throughput is stupidly high since it's all within AWS network. 2GB should only take seconds.

Comment: We have lots of internal applications which write the logs to internal folders, which we mount on to a VM and then sync to Amazon s3. I am not sure if i can fit in ebs volumes.

Comment: I see. Then is your internal network allowed to link with AWS? If so, you should consider AWS direct connect: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/aws-direct-connect-amazon-to-amazon.html